# Query on Identity Column on MS SQL DB

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, identity

I have created table in MS SQL 2008 with one identity column(Start Value - 1 and Increment is also 1) and 4 other columns. I am accessing this DB from C# ASP.NET. Used to push data only for the non identity column. Identity column will auto increment itself.

As of now i am manually querying the column value with the remaining for columns. But I am facing problem if all the other four column values are equal i am not getting the exact value which i am looking for

Now my query is, Is there any why in C# where I can get the value of the newly created identity column whenever new record is created.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question actually lies in SQL Server.  You can run:

```
SELECT @@identity
```

after your insert to get the last inserted row identity.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933167(v=sql.80).aspx

EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS:

Consider using SCOPE_IDENTITY() as referenced here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259185(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: You might consider `SCOPE_IDENTITY` over `@@IDENTITY` and build an `INSERT` statement that is coupled with `; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

Comment: Could do that.  Assuming proper query architecture, it should not make a significant difference though.

Comment: It does not in general, but it's a good practice for scalability. We deal in transactions in the millions per day; `@@IDENTITY` breaks down in that type of environment.

Comment: **NEVER EVER USE @@IDENTITY** use SCOPE_IDENTITY().  throw in a trigger and a log table with an identity column and you will have problems.

Comment: @BrianP - Nothing to do with "proper query architecture" If someone adds a trigger to the table in the future that inserts into a table with an id column. `@@IDENTITY` will definitely return incorrect results as it returns last id value generated by the *session*. `SCOPE_IDENTITY` has the correct semantics here.

Comment: Hadn't thought about it from the trigger angle. I tend to stay away from triggers when possible.  It adds complexity for the devs that come after me...

Comment: Edited to reflect comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Which will returns the primary key value of the recently inserted row

Answer (score 0):

In SQL terms you can output the records back if you wish it. But how you might apply this to C# is up to you. Example:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A (SOMETHING, SOMETHINGELSE, RANDOMVAL3)
OUTPUT inserted.A_ID, inserted.SOMETHING, inserted.SOMETHINGELSE, inserted.RANDOMVAL3
SELECT 'ASD','DOSD', 123
```

But unless you're using merge, you can't use OUTPUT to print out any values from joining tables from an INSERT. But that's another matter entirely, I think.

Also, it's hardly good practice to bounce this data between the application and the DB all the time, so I'd look to alternatives if possible.

Comment: Hi Kahn, Can u please help me with some sample query.. Thanks in advance